Solving expression with incomplete gamma function and plotting
In the following code I want to plot fplot1 vs P by substituting r from f[r]==0 in the expression of fplot1. I think the expression of incomplete Gamma function is making problem here. Can any one tell me what am i doing wrong here?
Duplicate Question- here
\[Epsilon] = Integrate[1/(E^(r*t)*t), {t, 1, Infinity}]; 
f[r_] := 1 - (2*M)/r - (Q^2*(r^3 - r^2 + 2*r - 6))/(E^r*(6*r^2)) - \[CapitalLambda]*(r^2/3) + (Q^2*\[Epsilon]*r^2)/6 - c/r^(1 + 3*\[Omega]
Clear[fPlot1, c, Q, \[Omega], M]; 
c = 0.1; 
Q = 0.5; 
\[Omega] = -3^(-1); 
M = 2; 
fPlot1[P_] := D[f[r], r]/(4*Pi) /. Last[NSolve[f[r] == 0 && r > 0, r, Reals]]; 
Plot[fPlot1[P], {P, 0, 0.3}, PlotRange -> {0, 0.5}, PlotStyle -> Green, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}]


You haven't defined \[CapitalLambda] and the RHS of the definition of fPlot1[P_] does not contain P
